# How to write a concise list of variables in table of a freq when the variables are differentiated only by a suffix?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with some variables named `sx` for `x` = 1 to *n*.

Is it possible to write a `freq` which gives the same result as:

```
proc freq data=prova;
table s1 * s2 * s3 * ... * sn /list missing;
run;
```

but without listing all the names of the variables?

I would like an output like this:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4  Frequency
A                  10
A   E             100
A   E   J   F     300
B                  10
B   E             100
B   E   J   F     300
```

but with an istruction like this (which, of course, is invented):

```
proc freq data=prova;
table s1:sn /list missing;
run;
```

Comment: If you just want the counts then use PROC SUMMARY (aka PROC MEANS) with NWAY option and CLASS statement.

Comment: If you don't want the counts or percentages then PROC SUMMARY is definitely the way to go.  Or PROC SORT NODUPKEY.

Comment: @Tom I like the output of the freq, I don't only want to write `s1 * s2 * s3 * ... * sn`, I'll try with your answer and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to build up the string "S1*S2*..." then you could use a DO loop or a macro %DO loop and put the result into a macro variable.

```
data _null_;
  length namelist $200;
  do i=1 to 10;
    namelist=catx('*',namelist,cats('S',i));
  end;
  call symputx('namelist',namelist);
run;
```

But here is an easy way to make such a macro variable **from ANY variable list** not just those with numeric suffixes.

First get the variables names into a dataset.  PROC TRANSPOSE is a good way if you use the OBS=0 dataset option so that you only get the _NAME_ column.

```
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) ;
  var s1-s10 ;
run;
```

Then use PROC SQL to stuff the names into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select _name_
    into :namelist separated by '*'
    from &syslast
  ;
quit;
```

Then you can use the macro variable in your TABLES statement.

```
proc freq data=have ;
  tables &namelist / list missing ;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `PROC SUMMARY` instead?
Here is an example using two variables from SASHELP.CARS.
So this is PROC FREQ code.

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
  where make in: ('A','B');
  tables make*type / list;
run;
```

Here is way to get counts using PROC SUMMARY

```
proc summary missing nway data=sashelp.cars ;
  where make in: ('A','B');
  class make type ;
  output out=want;
run;
proc print data=want ;
run;
```

If you need to calculate the percentages you can instead use the WAYS statement to get both the overall and the individual cell counts. And then add a data step to calculate the percentages.

```
proc summary missing data=sashelp.cars ;
  where make in: ('A','B');
  class make type ;
  ways 0 2 ;
  output out=want;
run;
data want ;
  set want ;
  retain total;
  if _type_=0 then total=_freq_;
  percent=100*_freq_/total;
run;
```

So if you have 10 variables you would use

```
ways 0 10 ;
class s1-s10 ;
```

Comment: Effectively, a simple `proc summary missing data=have nway;
  class s1-sn;
  output out=want;
run;` does the trick. Sorry, I didn't understand before.

Answer (score 0):

Car':

In short, no. There is no shortcut syntax for specifying a variable list that crosses dimension.
In long, yes -- if you create a surrogate variable that is an equivalent crossing.

## Discussion

Sample data generator:

```
%macro have(top=5);
  %local index;
  data have;
    %do index = 1 %to &top;
    do s&index = 1 to 2+ceil(3*ranuni(123));
    %end;
    array V s:;

    do _n_ = 1 to 5*ranuni(123);
      x = ceil(100*ranuni(123));

      if ranuni(123) < 0.1 then do;
        ix = ceil(&top*ranuni(123));
        h = V(ix);
        V(ix) = .;
        output;
        V(ix) = h;
      end;
      else
        output;
    end;

    %do index = 1 %to &top;
    end;
    %end;
  run;
%mend;

%have;
```

As you probably noticed `table s:` created one freq per s* variable.
For example:

```
title "One table per variable";
proc freq data=have;
  tables s: / list missing ;
run;
```

There is no shortcut syntax for specifying a variable list that crosses dimension.

*NOTE: If you specify out=, the column names in the output data set will be the last variable in the level.  So for above, the out= table will have a column "s5", but contain counts corresponding to combinations for each s1 through s5.*

At each dimensional level you can use a variable list, as in `level1 * (sublev:) * leaf`.  The same caveat for out= data applies.

Now, reconsider the original request discretely (no-shortcut) crossing all the s* variables:

```
title "1 table - 5 columns of crossings";
proc freq data=have;
  tables s1*s2*s3*s4*s5 / list missing out=outEach;
run;
```

And, compare to what happens when a data step view uses a variable list to compute a surrogate value corresponding to the discrete combinations reported above.

```
data haveV / view=haveV;
  set have;
  crossing = catx(' * ', of s:);  * concatenation of all the s variables;
  keep crossing;
run;

title "1 table - 1 column of concatenated crossings";
proc freq data=haveV;
  tables crossing / list missing out=outCat;
run;
```

Reality check with COMPARE, I don't trust eyeballs.  If zero rows with differences (per `noequal`) then the out= data sets have identical counts.

```
proc compare noprint base=outEach compare=outCat out=diffs outnoequal;
  var count;
run;
----- Log -----
NOTE: There were 31 observations read from the data set WORK.OUTEACH.
NOTE: There were 31 observations read from the data set WORK.OUTCAT.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DIFFS has 0 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE COMPARE used (Total process time)
```

Comment: The numbers are the same, but the output have only a variable `crossing` with values `A * B * C`, whereas I prefer the solution I accepted, because there are `S1, S2, ...` with their values shown separately.